# can we make use of polymorphism by inheriting an empty class?

Tags: java

I want to use Generics concept and create an ArrayList that needs to take different types of objects so I want to  create an empty class called `ObjectType` and inherit it via '`Person and Animal`' classes and want to create ArrayList as below

```
List<? extends ObjectType> list=new ArrayList<Persons>();
```

but it is not working what is the solution?

Comment: Can you mention your class implementation?

Comment: public class ObjectType(){
public class Person extends ObjectType(){
public name,location,id,salary;
//followed by a constructor for initialisation
}
then want to add perosn objects to arraylist as below
List<? extends ObjectType> list=new ArrayList<Person>();

Comment: If you are creating empty class then i would suggest to use interface rather then class and implement your animal and person class.

Comment: There is one correction public class ObjectType{} rather then public class ObjectType(){}

Comment: Don't put more information into comments, always update your question instead. Or can you really read that code only comments you made?

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would use an `interface` rather than a class wherever possible as it is simpler and more flexible.

What you can write is

```
interface ObjectType { }

class Animal implements ObjectType { }

class Person implements ObjectType { }

List<ObjectType> objects = new ArrayList<>();
```

This might not do what you expect, however how you solve this depends on what you need the List to do.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to use Generics(? extends ObjectType) in collection

Comment: @NagendhraKumarSunkara If you do, you won't be able to add anything to such a collection. Can you provide a more detailed example?